# I want to design a metro-style login page,could someone give me some suggestions?

Tags: windows-phone-7, authentication, styles, microsoft-metro

Many people think that no tile is not metro-style,so I want to add some tiles in my login page.But page's function is simple,add the tiles maybe destroy the whole page layout.Could someone give me some suggestions or tell me the metro-style login page's characteristics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can develop the page using Twitter Bootstrap http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/, a framework that you may already know, developed by Twitter. It helps you prototyping fast but it is also possible to use it for production. It creates a layout grid. It can be fixed or fluid and it is responsive.

Then after you downloaded Bootstrap you can use a theme for bootstrap called Bootmetro that you can find in this Github repository: http://aozora.github.com/bootmetro/

Comment: Ok,thank you for you advice,I will go to learn the bootstrap later.

Comment: you are welcome. please vote if you find the answer useful. I can also provide you tutorials and resources for Bootstrap. Anyway the official documentation is the best place to start. @BruceLi